# Why do we use odd ratios rather than using conditional probabillity?

Tags: probability, machine-learning

The OR represents the odds that an outcome will occur given a particular exposure, this is very analogous to the concept of conditional probability except that the formula for conditional probability makes a much better connection with its definition, why do we use the odd ratios whatsoever when we can just find $P(A|B)$ and then use $$\frac{p}{1-p}$$

to find the odds that the outcome A will happen given that B is guaranteed to happen.

Comment: I do not follow your question.  Odds and probability are related concepts however they are different in terms of how the information is presented.  The probability of rolling a six on a standard fair six-sided die is $\frac{1}{6}$.  The odds of doing so was $1:5$ (*or if you insist on writing this as a fraction rather than using a colon... as $\frac{1}{5}$ which you will notice is indeed $\dfrac{\frac{1}{6}}{1-\frac{1}{6}}$*).  This has nothing to do with conditional probability however...  "*Why do we use odds whatsoever...*" because of historical reasons only and personal preference.

Comment: I'm talking about "odd ratios" rather than just merely "odds", in the question I'm enquiring about why use odd ratios for an outcome A exposed to B when we can use "odds of A happening given B"

Comment: What do you think the difference is between those?  The phrases mean the same thing to me.  "odds" vs "odds ratios" mean the same thing to me.  "A exposed to B" vs "A given B" mean the same thing to me.

Comment: To me the difference is that the latter is a ratio involving the former. Mathematically the odds of A given B and the odd ratio of A to B are not the same and that's what confuses me.